# Getting a Full Response (not just the body) from Angular 4 HTTP Calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a full response from my HTTP calls. According to the Angular documentation I should set my HTTP call **"options"** as `{observe: 'response'}`

**I get the following error if I do that:**

```
Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<IItem[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IItem[]>'. Type 'HttpResponse<IItem[]>' is not assignable to type 'IItem[]'. Property 'includes' is missing in type 'HttpResponse<IItem[]>'.
```

I think my concepts regarding **Observables** & **Typing/Casting** aren't that clear.

I've got a HTTP Get request which is returning an observable and Strong typing it into an array of items (See below)

```
getItems(): Observable <IItem[]>{
    return this._http.get<IItem[]>(url, {observe: 'response'})
    .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
};
```

I tried setting `getUsers(): Observable <HttpResponse<IUser[]>>` which solved the above error but within my `subscribe` I got the following error when I try to assign the returned data to a local variable `this.item = data;` where `item` is declared as `item: Item[]`

```
Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<IItem[]>>' is not assignable to type 'IItem[]
```

**So my questions are:**

1. How can I resolve the above error (and why did this error occur)?
2. This might be a stupid question but if `._http.get<IItem[]>` is already setting the expected "type" of response do I still need to set the `getItems(): Observable <IItem[]>` methods return type?

I think I'm not understanding some basic concept that's causing this confusion. Any help will be appreciated. I'm new to Angular 4 so please be gentle.

Comment: what do you mean by `full response`? and do you use `http` or `httpclient`?

Comment: Assuming you use HttpClient [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) should be what you looking for.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com By full response I mean getting headers, status codes and everything else. Currently it's only returning the `body`. I am using `HttpClient`

Comment: @ShaharGalukman Thanks for the comment. Thats exactly what I did the only difference being my `subscribe` is in my component while the `http.get` is within my service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpClient.get` method is defined to use generic type `T`:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    ...
}): Observable<T>;
```

So since since you pass `<IItem[]>` to the `get` method here `this._http.get<IItem[]>` according to the definition the `get` method returns `HttpResponse<IItem[]>` object. However you declare your method `getItems` to return `IItem[]` and hence you get the error:

> Type 'Observable<HttpResponse<IItem[]>>' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable<IItem[]>'.

To fix it, you need to return `IItem[]`. This can be done by extracting body of type `IItem[]` from `HttpResponse<IItem[]>` and return it. `do` operator can't return anything so you have to use `map` operator for that:

```
this._http.get<IItem[]>('url', {observe: 'response'})
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .map(data => data.body)
```

Comment: Hii I love you articles :)

Comment: @yurzui I will :)

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine, thanks! Spending so much time on them, it's cheering to know people benefit from them. Also writing the book now, [check this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/would-you-buy-a-book-on-angular-change-detection-8239a8ef64b7)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com First of all Thank you so much for the explanation! This makes sense. Basically `httpClient.get` is returning `<httpresponse<IItem>>` while the `getItems()` method is expecting to get data resembling `Item[]` (I hope I got this right). Also you just got another reader. Im gonna start reading your articles! Have you done any articles on `Error Handling` within Angular 4/Observables?

Comment: @Skywalker, yeah, you got it right. Good for you, I write about very unique stuff. However, I don't have anything on `Error Handling` yet. I'm into very deep stuff now, reverse-engineering TS compiler. Will publish an article on my findings in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

this should work :

```
  getItems(): Observable <IItem[]>{
            return this.http
            .get<IItem[]>(url, {observe: 'response'})
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .map( (r: HttpResponse<IItem[]> )  => r.body )
        };
```